# $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ independent random variables are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. $P(X_1<X_2<...<X_n)=?$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ independent random variables are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

So, we say that $P(X_1<X_2<...<X_n)=\frac{1}{n!}$

But why is that the correct answer? How do we calculate it?

According to the answer, my guess is: This case is like arranging $n$ people in a row. we have $n!$
permutations for that, and only one satisfies the requirement. Thus, we get $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Is that the way of thinking that should be?

Comment: As always, $$\mathbb P\{(X_1,...,X_n)\in A\}=\int_A f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)\,\mathrm d x_1...\,\mathrm d x_n.$$ Therefore, in your case $$\mathbb P\{X_1<...<X_n\}=\int_0^1\,\mathrm d x_n\int_{0}^{x_n}dx_{n-1}\int_0^{x_{n-1}}\,\mathrm d x_{n-2}...\int_0^{x_2}\,\mathrm d x_1=...$$

Comment: Is there any other way, without integrals? something "simpler". We haven't learned integrals yet.

Comment: I would be surprised that you can compute it without using integrals... in any cases, I don't see how...

Comment: Without integrals, the only way to think about the problem is that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, so their occurrence in any of the orders is equally likely and there are $n!$ orders.

Comment: @MathLover that's my new favorite (pithy) way to compute that integral, which as come up for me in other contexts

Comment: @operatorerror just out of curiosity, what's the other context?

Comment: @MathLover finding a solution to $-u''=\lambda u$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ by making the ansatz $u(x,\lambda)=\sum_{n\geq 0}u_n(x)\lambda^n$ (which is justified by stability of ode facts). By formally differentiating, you get the recursive ode $-u_n''=u_{n-1}$ and this integral for $u_n$

Comment: @MathLover I guess you can sort of adapt this approach in a less contrived way: there are n! equivalent integrals to the integral $I$ in the one above, and if you add al of these together you get the volume of the unit cube, so $I*n!=1$

Comment: @operatorerror this is exactly the solution I wrote. The volume of the integral is just the probability of a particular permutation.

Comment: @Thomas True, I confess I had not read your answer. I thought it was nice because it did not reference any probability, although the idea is pretty much identical (hence "adapt")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is zero probability that two variables are equal. We can forget this case of zero measure.

Take a permutation of indices $\sigma$. Consider $p(\sigma)$ the probability that the variables are ordered accordingly.

By symmetry $p(\sigma)$ does not depend on $\sigma$ and the sum over all permutations is $1$, hence the conclusion that $p(\sigma)=1/n!$.

It does not even matter that the variables are uniformly distributed (e.g. could be normally distributed R.V.). The symmetry argument always applies.

Essentially the argument is very similar to what to propose, only one has to reframe it into more formal probabilistic terms.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)